# Convert hierarchical JSON files to hierarchical jQuery divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

How do I loop through two PARENT-CHILD-relationship (on simple ID PKEY and FKEY) JSON files and display them as a list of divs that are:

1. hierarchical - where child/FKEY divs only appear under the parent/PKEY div (show up as parent-child-child, parent-child-child-child, etc.)
2. expandable - these child/FKEY divs are `display:none` until you click the parent/PKEY div; i.e., items appear/disappear when you click the PKEY div, using jQuery's `$(panelID).slideToggle(speed)` method
3. able to be toggled with a separate checkbox div if the last key-value pair in the parent div OR child div exists and has key="DEPRECATED"
4. sortable - *Just Kidding*

*jQuery* offers me both `parseJSON` and cool display functions, and I give it atrociously horrible JS-debugging skills in return.

Edit: Here are the two JSON files in question:

```
types.json:

{"objtype":[{"NAME":"Animal","ID":"15","DEPRECATED":""},{"NAME":"Vegetable","ID":"8"},{"NAME":"Mineral","ID":"2","DEPRECATED":""}]}

objs.json:

{"objinstance":[{"DATEBOUGHT":"2014-08-26 00:00:00.0","OBJTYPEID":"8","OBJNAME":"Fruit salad consisting of oranges and mangoes","OBJID":"454","DATEEXPIRES":"2014-09-01 00:00:00.0","DEPRECATED":""},{"DATEBOUGHT":"2014-08-26 00:00:00.0","OBJTYPEID":"8","OBJNAME":"Spicy V-8 juice","OBJID":"499","DATEEXPIRES":"2015-01-02 00:00:00.0"},{"DATEBOUGHT":"2014-08-26 00:00:00.0","OBJTYPEID":"2","OBJNAME":"Rental agreement for new apartment","OBJID":"2885","DATEEXPIRES":"2015-08-25 00:00:00.0"},{"DATEBOUGHT":"2014-08-26 00:00:00.0","OBJTYPEID":"2","OBJNAME":"Salt","OBJID":"1033","DATEEXPIRES":"","DEPRECATED":""},{"DATEBOUGHT":"","OBJTYPEID":"15","OBJNAME":"Koko the Monkey","OBJID":"68","DATEEXPIRES":"","DEPRECATED":""},{"DATEBOUGHT":"","OBJTYPEID":"15","OBJNAME":"Bubbles the Clown","OBJID":"69","DATEEXPIRES":"","DEPRECATED":""}]}
```

Comment: So, what have you tried to achieve your wishlist? What problems are you facing? Include relevant and reproducible code in your question.

Comment: perhaps have a look at this example from d3.js http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025

Comment: @abhitalks I should've said I'm having trouble with structuring it, not debugging it.

Comment: @haxxxton nice link thanks, that one's great and fits the purpose, although it doesn't use jQuery which I was hoping to see used

Comment: @abhitalks I haven't gotten much achieved, tbh. I can't seem to structure it properly, and that would seem to be a necessary first step. I couldn't locate a particularly simple enough example on the net, nor a complex enough example in the tutorials. So I was hoping someone might be able to show the div structure here. Thanks for your comment too

Comment: @haxxxton that's really cool and I can use it. (and will). but I'm really interested in the jQuery answer as well if anyone has a link to an example that uses JSON and jQuery to achieve it. It'd be a denser code than 'flare's, which is brilliant & thanks again.

Comment: @haxxxton one other thing, 'flare' uses only one JSON file that contains its own children. I'd like to be able to use two, that way they'd be independently editable/saveable. I edited the question to include the two JSON files, if you want to have a look. Cheers

Comment: heres a jquery library that will do out of the box what i think you're looking for: https://github.com/yesmeck/jquery-jsonview

Comment: @AquaQuartz: I have added a simple enough example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extremely simple example of how you could generate HTML markup based on your data in JSON.

***Algorithm***:

1. Parse JSON string into Javascript objects
2. Iterate parent data
3. For each parent data, create parent `div` and add required content into it.
4. Iterate child data, search for common `id`
5. For each child data which matches the parent `id`, create child `div`, add required content into it, and finally append to the parent `div`
6. Append parent `div` to a container or body
7. Rinse, lather, repeat
8. Create CSS styles as per your taste

.

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/h3nbwc1f/***

***Snippet***:

```js
var typesString = '{"objtype":[{"NAME":"Animal","ID":"15","DEPRECATED":""},{"NAME":"Vegetable","ID":"8"},{"NAME":"Mineral","ID":"2","DEPRECATED":""}]}';
var objsString = '{"objinstance":[{"DATEBOUGHT":"2014-08-26 00:00:00.0","OBJTYPEID":"8","OBJNAME":"Fruit salad consisting of oranges and mangoes","OBJID":"454","DATEEXPIRES":"2014-09-01 00:00:00.0","DEPRECATED":""},{"DATEBOUGHT":"2014-08-26 00:00:00.0","OBJTYPEID":"8","OBJNAME":"Spicy V-8 juice","OBJID":"499","DATEEXPIRES":"2015-01-02 00:00:00.0"},{"DATEBOUGHT":"2014-08-26 00:00:00.0","OBJTYPEID":"2","OBJNAME":"Rental agreement for new apartment","OBJID":"2885","DATEEXPIRES":"2015-08-25 00:00:00.0"},{"DATEBOUGHT":"2014-08-26 00:00:00.0","OBJTYPEID":"2","OBJNAME":"Salt","OBJID":"1033","DATEEXPIRES":"","DEPRECATED":""},{"DATEBOUGHT":"","OBJTYPEID":"15","OBJNAME":"Koko the Monkey","OBJID":"68","DATEEXPIRES":"","DEPRECATED":""},{"DATEBOUGHT":"","OBJTYPEID":"15","OBJNAME":"Bubbles the Clown","OBJID":"69","DATEEXPIRES":"","DEPRECATED":""}]}';

var types = JSON.parse(typesString);
var objs = JSON.parse(objsString);

types.objtype.forEach(function(item, idx) {
    var $parent = $("<div class='parent' />");
    var $label = $("<label>").text(item.ID + ': ' + item.NAME).attr('for', 'c' + idx);
 var $input = $('<input type="checkbox">').attr('id', 'c' + idx);
 $parent.append($label);
    $parent.append($input);
    objs.objinstance.forEach(function(item2) {
        if (item2.OBJTYPEID == item.ID) {
            var $child = $("<div class='child' />");
            var txt2 = item2.OBJID + ': ' + item2.OBJNAME;
            $child.text(txt2);
            $parent.append($child);
        }
    });
    $("#wrap").append($parent);
});
```

```css
div#wrap {
    font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}
div.parent {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 8px; margin: 4px;
}
div.child {
    border: 1px solid green;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 0px; margin: 0px;
    opacity: 0; height: 0px;
    transition: all 250ms;
}
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked  ~ div.child {
    padding: 8px; margin: 8px;
    opacity: 1; height: auto;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

Comment: I am trying to get this running now, but it looks like all (or if not, at least most) of the answer, in compact form. I can't upvote it w/o 15 rep but I've been piecing these snippets together to see if I can get it to run in-browser. Meanwhile, thank you for exploring this structure; as aforementioned it looks like a quite **compact** method of coding the question's answer, which is what I was looking for. Cheers

Comment: @AquaQuartz: You may want to accept this answer if you found it useful.